# usb3 bug report <disconnects all devices>

Tags: usb, kernel

I had this bug in arch linux , i switched to manjaro and i had it there too.
Then i switched to ubuntu and i have it here too.
It's kernel related and i can understand that since kernel is very similar in all distros, i have the same bug everywhere.

[dmesg](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2F96zW4Zb4/)
 [lspci-vvnn](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZgNpJ87mzm/)

lsusb: `Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

uname -a: Linux titan 5.0.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 1 13:51:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

version: Ubuntu 5.0.0-25.26~18.04.1-generic 5.0.18

Before reporting, i tested kernel 4.19.X too and i have the same issue.

It happens more often when i start building at my android environment.

Sorry for reporting it here , but when i try open a bug report here:https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs
it redirects me to the documentation page where i have to spend a lot of time to read and it doesn't have an easy button to just report a bug.
Btw why is it so hard to report a bug ? If apport can't "catch" a bug, do i have to read 2k+ lines to report it ?...

Comment: The easiest way I find to report bugs is `ubuntu-bug <package>` (which does assume you know the package, but because you believe it's a kernel issue you already have that), refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs.   This is a support site, and bugs belong on launchpad  (*and you haven't reported it here, as you cannot!*)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: but it doesn't tell me how to report it or where...
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Hardware_bug_reports_.28linux_kernel.2C_xorg.2C_sound.2C_etc..29

Comment: I mentioned `ubuntu-bug` which is done from CLI/bash on your box. It will gather up the information required (about your specific box, release etc) & submit online... See the "*Reporting a crash in the stable release*" section (or search for ubuntu-bug).  If you have a crash file in /var/crash/, use that crash file as the parameter (`apport` (ubuntu-bug) will work out much of the details for you)

Comment: guiverc , https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic , pressing bug report it redirects to an answer that tells everyone to use "ubuntu-bug packagename" , but this is a kernel module bug. It doesn't have a package name. 
If you don't have a link where i can really submit a bug, do not redirect me to useless guides please. I don't have time to read all these to report a bug...
I thought the open source community would be happy to know there is a bug , in order to improve the code... not even the lame windows don't have such a hard procedure to report a bug

Comment: quiverc,
Sorry now i saw latest comment.
It doesn't have any crash anywhere. Suddenly all devices disappear and thats all

Comment: and dont undervote me or close me before its even solved.
The https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs clearly sais that i can talk about it here before i submit the bug.
If i could submit it.................

Comment: You stated it was a kernel bug.  Firstly I'd look for a crash file in /var/crash/ as already stated, crashes should result in a crash file (though I'd not expect one for a kernel panic).  Kernel bugs can be submitted with `ubuntu-bug linux` (as the kernel is linux; `apport` will get more details from your system as it runs). The page I mentioned mentions here for support (not bugs), and I'd recommend IRC from that page if you need a walk-thru (this is a Q&A site).  Be detailed when firefox opens and reports on launchpad.  (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs)

Comment: If the module that has the problem isn't from a Ubuntu package or repository (thus no package) - you'll need to file it wherever the module comes from (git, or wherever it came from will have their own bug procedures, and likely won't use launchpad).

Comment: thank you. ubuntu-bug linux does the thing i need. will report it next time it happens so that it can also collect all needed logs on it's own

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I find to report bugs is `ubuntu-bug <package>` (which does assume you know the package, but because you believe it's a kernel issue you already have that), refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs. See the "Reporting a crash in the stable release" section (or search for ubuntu-bug).

This is a support site, and bugs belong on launchpad.

`ubuntu-bug` is entered from CLI/bash on your box. It will gather up the information required (about your specific box, release etc) & submit online...  If you have a crash file in `/var/crash/`, use that crash file as the parameter (apport [`ubuntu-bug`] will work out much of the details for you)

Kernel bugs can be submitted with `ubuntu-bug linux` (as the kernel is linux; apport will get more details (kernel version etc) from your system as it runs). I'd recommend IRC from that *reporting-bugs* page if you need a walk-thru (*this is a Q&A site*). Be detailed when firefox opens and reports on launchpad. (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs)

If the module that has the problem isn't from a Ubuntu package or repository (thus no package) - you'll need to file it wherever the module comes from (git, or wherever the module came from will its own bug procedures, and mostly likely won't be launchpad used by Ubuntu).

*If you do file the bug, thank you for taking the time to report this bug and helping to make Ubuntu better.*

Comment: comments converted to question & answer format; fitting site aims hopefully.